# expected conditions with JSON objects

Tags: protractor

I am making an API call which returns a JSON Structure in the response:

```
{
"tags": [],
"scope": "all",
"tenant_id": "0",    
"version": 1,
"type": "tenant",
"description": "",
"name": "3",   
"body":{
    "settings": {},
    "tenant_id": "2",       
 }
}
```

When I am trying to compare

```
expect(res.body.name).toBe(3);
```

or

```
expect(res.body.name).toEqual(3);
```

It fails and gives follwoing error:

```
Expected '3' to be 3.
```

or

```
Expected '3' to Equal 3.
```

Comment: @Suresh has the right answer, if you need to double check you can always do `console.log(typeof(res.body.name))` which in your case would return `string`

Comment: Thanks this helped `console.log(typeof(res.body.name))` returns string hence used `toContain()` and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Your are equating string '3' to number 3, that is the reason for the failure. You can use the following code:

```
 expect(res.body.name).toEqual("3");
```

OR

```
expect(res.body.name).toBe("3");
```

Comment: Tried this but this also fails: `Expected '3' to equal '"3"'.`

Comment: Can you print the console.log(typeof res.body.name)?, so that we can update code based on res.body.name type

Comment: @soniasharma It appears that your output is literally `'3'`  That is, it's not just the string representation of 3, but the string representation of a tick, 3, and tick.  That is why `.toContain` works for you.  Perhaps, if you wanted, you could try: `expect(res.body.name).toEqual('\'3\'');` or `expect(res.body.name).toEqual("'3'");`  It all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`"name": "3",` makes it sound as though `expect(res.body.name).toEqual('3');` should work since "3" is a string.

Also in that same vein:
`expect(res.body.name).toBe('3');` in case your code style prefers === checks over ==
`expect(Number(res.body.name)).toEqual(3);` in case you need to be expecting the number 3 regardless of the exact type of 3.

If the api response was `"name": 3,`, your tests would be good as is, but it seems as though the implementation has it stored as a string. Either file a bug if it needs to be a number, have your expectations be strings as well, or convert the api response to a number before asserting.

I don't think you need to expect literally `'3'`, just `3` the string rather than `3` the number.